# Check multiple selected options, if found value show Div

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, show-hide

I have a group in a select that if chosen it shows a Div.

It works great the problem is that I have several other selects with the same options and groups.

And if you choose the group that shows the div, and then you pick a group that don't this one hides again.

Selects are created dynamically so you can create or delete the rows, if you delete a row where you created a select and chose and option of the group that shows div, then u will see div even if there's no select with the option to show the div.

Anyway of checking the options selected to show or not show div?
I wanna show the div if at least one of the group "Unique" option is selected. And if it checks and theres no option of that group, then hide.

```js
 function doSomething(element) {
  // get optgroup
  let optgroup = element.options[element.options.selectedIndex].closest('optgroup').getAttribute('label')
  console.log(optgroup)
  if (optgroup == 'Unique') {
    $("#extras").show()
  } else {
    $("#extras").hide()
  }
}
```

```css
.extras {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select" name="skills[]" onchange='doSomething(this)' required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select" name="skills[]" onchange='doSomething(this)' required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select" name="skills[]" onchange='doSomething(this)' required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="mt-5 extras extras" id="extras">
  <h4 class="text-dark">Check</h4>
  Increased through making items, sewing and cooking.<br>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkpoint" checked required/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set this up as event delegates it will be easier to manage and consolidate your code. Set up a listener to react to the select menus - I have set it up on the table so that you can create new select menus inside the table and they'll inherit the listener.

Then, just check all selects to see if they are using the target optgroup to turn on or off the div.

Some other notes:

- I gave your select menu's identifiable classes as to be easier to select with jQuery
- I make all your code jQuery, where is was half and half before.
- You can use `toggle()` rather than show/hide and just provide a boolean for the argument. A true means `show()`, flase means `hide()`
- I set up a delete button to show how it can integrate with this flow

```js
$('.skillTable').on('change', ".skillSelect", function() {
  checkExtras()
})

$('.delete').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('tr').remove();
  checkExtras();
})

function checkExtras() {
  let hasExtras = false;
  $(".skillSelect").each(function(i, o) {
    let optgroup = $(o).find(':checked').closest('optgroup').attr('label');
    if (optgroup === 'Unique') hasExtras = true;
  })
  $("#extras").toggle(hasExtras)
}
```

```css
.extras {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-floating mb-3 mt-3">
  <table class='skillTable'>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select skillSelect" name="skills[]" required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select> <button class='delete'>delete</button>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select skillSelect" name="skills[]" required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select> <button class='delete'>delete</button>

      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td><input class="form-control input-lg email" type="email" name="mail[]" required />
      </td>
      <td>
        <select class="form-select skillSelect" name="skills[]" required>
          <option class="blank" value=""></option>
          <optgroup Class="unique" label="Common">
            <option value="Extraction">Extraction</option>
            <option value="Hunting">Hunting</option>
            <option value="Farming">Farming</option>
          </optgroup>
          <optgroup class="unique" label="Unique">
            <option value="Diplomacy">Diplomacy</option>
            <option value="Survival">Survival</option>
          </optgroup>
        </select>
        <button class='delete'>delete</button>
      </td>
      <td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<div class="mt-5 extras extras" id="extras">
  <h4 class="text-dark">Check</h4>
  Increased through making items, sewing and cooking.<br>
  <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" name="checkpoint" checked required/>
</div>
```

Comment: Where can I learn more about js?

Comment: Loads of places, doing exactly what you're doing. Building things, trying to make them work, then researching why they aren't working or how to build them better. This site is great for that. Outside of that DIY, there are loads of resources from videos to tutorials to articles to classes you can find via google search

Comment: If you are still there, can you explain a bit more? The first part of your js I think it's the listener you said? seconda part the delete button and the last part can you explain the logic a bit more? Thank you.
Works perfect for what I was looking to use it.